# FileVault password not working from standby

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake, filevault

I have several users on my MacBook but have FileVault setup with only one uses, lets say it is called 'admin'. So when the MacBook goes into standby mode (hibernate) and the FileVault password is requested, the only user who can unlock it is 'admin'.

This used to work fine, but after reinstalling the MacBook this setup has stopped working. When the system wakes from standby, the 'admin' password isn't accepted. I am sure the password is correct, since I can use is fine when I start from boot.

I have already changed the password, but that didn't help.
I am running macOS Sierra with all the updates.

What is wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the password is not the problem, but the keyboard is. After waking up from standby the keyboard and touchpad stutter, so some keys become missing when typing in the password.

Comment: I have this same problem after a repair. I went through a lengthy case regarding this with Apple and could not get a resolution other than "type slowly", and have done multiple erase/reinstall cycles to try to solve it. Would love to know what does this.

Answer (score 0):

The recent [macOS Sierra 10.12.3 update](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207462), though it did not call out this issue, fixed this problem for me. The EFI password prompt that appears when the system comes out of hibernation no longer drops keystrokes, nor does it appear to stutter when I circle my finger on the trackpad.